# Return from an over ridden method of return type void in an inner class

Tags: java, android, mysql

I am trying to develop an app in Android Studio. I'm stuck in this situation. 
I'm using an AsyncHttp client to get a list of table names from a MySQL database. I'm calling the below function from the UI activity to populate the values in the Spinner. But I'm unable to return the values.The value is retrieved in the inner class and inside an overridden method whose return type is void. Please look at the code to understand further.

```
public void fetchAvailableLocations ()
{
    AsyncHttpClient httpClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
    RequestParams requestParams = new RequestParams();

    String _URL = ""; // Enter URL here

    byte[] retreivedBytes;

    httpClient.post(_URL, requestParams, responseHandler, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {


        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int i, cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header[] headers, byte[] bytes) {
            retrievedBytes = bytes; //This is where I'm stuck

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int i, cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header[] headers, byte[] bytes, Throwable throwable) {
           //make toasts 
        }
    });
}
```

**One solution** I thought of is to create a static field in the UI activity, make a callback function which takes the bytes as the parameter and assigns the static field to the bytes parameter and then call it from the onSuceed method. But this route looks ugly. Is there a simpler way ?

I'm kinda new to Android Programming so please help.

Comment: Yes, there is. Use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to post an event in `onSuccess` with the contained data, and simply listen for that event wherever you need to and do whatever you wish with the data passed.

Comment: @Vucko. Thank You for the solution. But this method (let's call it B) is invoked by another one which is an onClick method (let's call it A). If I use this, won't it basically call another method (suscriber method, say C) which has to store the value in a static field so that the method A can use it when control returns from method B ? Isn't that the same as the other solution that I wrote above ? 
Please correct me if I'm wrong. It would mean I didn't understand how this works.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of extending use inheritance:

```
public class fetchAvailableLocationsClass implements AsyncHttpResponseHandler {

    public void fetchAvailableLocations() {
        AsyncHttpClient httpClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
        RequestParams requestParams = new RequestParams();

        String _URL = ""; // Enter URL here

        byte[] retreivedBytes;

        httpClient.post(_URL, requestParams, responseHandler, this);


        @Override
        public void onSuccess ( int i, cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header[] headers, byte[] bytes)
        {
            retrievedBytes = bytes; //This is where I'm stuck

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure ( int i, cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header[] headers,
        byte[] bytes, Throwable throwable){
            //make toasts
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You. But this method is a part of a class that has other methods each of which uses a different logic in the onSucess overriding. Also, I haven't extended the response handler. I'm using it directly.